# My Docker Containers are not Stopping correctly, every now and again during Elastic Beanstalk Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using the Azure Pipelines task for deploying 2 .NetCore apps in docker containers to elastic beanstalk. However every now and again the task fails to stop the containers from running with the error:

```
ERROR   ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:4567894531:task/225c1e26-209b-4cf3-af1b-6c211aecd2fd is STOPPED but containers are still running.
```

And this has started to happen more regular and our services go down for a much longer time then needed(while we trigger the redeploy the task)